# reuse laravel webapp core on many servers

Tags: php, laravel, multiple-instances

How is it possible to develop a webapp with laravel but use it multiple times / for many websites.

The goal is to have one "main" codebase to maintain and being able to install this on multiple servers and then just change website specific stuff (design, override controllers etc.)

Is it the easiest to write that "main" codebase as a package or are there other ways to go?

I read something about multi tenancy, which is supported by existing packages for laravel. But that sounded more to me that multiple websites have to be served by one server.

Comment: I personally don't like this, but if you want to do this, I think systemlinks can achieve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to go is create package with core features and extends this package per client needs inside standard laravel installation.